# Resize png smaller without loss of quality?

Tags: gimp, png

I am working with textures that I purchased in Second Life.  Most of these are 1024x1024.  However, i create children's clothing, when means most of these are in too large of a format for said children's clothing.  If I scale, or use map small tiles, the resulting picture becomes VERY blurry.  I have gotten around this, minorly, by increasing the AO of the mesh from 1024 to 2048, then use the 1024 (or reduced 512 image)...but it still doesn't quite work.

I have tried playing in Inkscape, trying to change the texture into an SVG, and reducing it.  However, i am still new, having just downloaded inkscape today.

Would appreciate the help...I primarily use Gimp, however, I can also do work in photoshop if instructions are in that format.

Comment: You can convert them to vectors with [Vector Magic](https://vectormagic.com), but the best solution would be to use [vector patterns](https://www.freepik.com/search?format=search&page=1&query=vector%20children%20patterns&sort=popular&type=vector)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing before/after images, so just a guess: periodic patterns like cloth, when scaled down, can be subject to [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

The non-intuitive fix is to blur the image before scaling it down, to remove detail that will anyway be sub-pixel in the target image. In Gimp 2.8, this corresponds to using a Gaussian blur of X pixels when scaling down by X (2px if you reduce the size to half...). In Gimp 2.10 the measure of the blur has changed, so that would be 6X pixels.